# autotools project - using prefix variable in scripts

Tags: gnu, autotools, configure

Having scripts in autotools project that are using some paths I want to forward prefix that is entered by user during ./configure to those scripts. Lets say I have a bash script that echo file in directory that is set during ./configure. What is the best way to do it? I am thinking about having myscript.sh.hpp that will be used by preprocessor and passing -DMYPATH to preprocessor to substitute it into myscript.sh.hpp to generate myscript.sh with appropriate path. Is that right direction?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you give a more specific example?

Comment: I have bash script like 

    #!/bin/bash
    ls /usr/sbin

I don't want to hardcode the path, I want It to be /usr/sbin by default, but available to be overwritten when installing. I.e. ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sbin && make will generate such file

#!/bin/bash
ls /usr/local/sbin

Comment: It's difficult know what's being asked here - is it a shell script substitution or 'hpp' source? (ha ha) - but it sounds like you need to use [AC_SUBST](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html#Setting-Output-Variables)

Comment: You do not want to use prefix to determine the path of bash.  prefix is the location your own software is being installed to, and it is unlikely that your package is installing bash.

Answer (score 1):

`prefix` is the location to which your software is installed, and is not really the correct place to look for things like `bash`.  It would be better to provide the user the ability to specify a bash interpreter or to probe PATH to find bash and use that value.  However, it is often desirable to reference `prefix` in a script.  The easiest way is to let `config.status` expand it.  In configure.ac:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([foo])
```

and in foo.in

```
@prefix@
```